# CakePHP htmlentities Issue

Tags: php, cakephp, html-entities

I'm having a strange problem with CakePHP's "Sanitize" class. What makes the problem strange is that the problem is only present in controllers, not in views.

Here's the URL:

http://example.com/testing/index?test=r%E9sum%E9

Here is the code:

```
echo '<p>Test: -' . 'résumé' . '-</p>';
echo '<p>Test: -' . $_GET['test'] . '-</p>';
echo '<p>Test: -' . Sanitize::html($_GET['test']) . '-</p>';
```

And this is what the above code outputs regardless of whether the code is being executed from the controller or the view:

```
Test: -résumé-

Test: -r�sum�-

Test: --
```

When I execute the code from the view, everything is fine, but when I execute the code from the controller, this warning is generated:

```
Warning: Warning (2): htmlentities() [<a href='function.htmlentities'>function.htmlentities</a>]: Invalid multibyte sequence in argument in [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev/cake/libs/sanitize.php, line 120]
```

Why is that warning only being generated from the controller and not the view? What can I do to fix it?

I've tried this using PHP 5.2.17 and 5.3.3. I've also tried multiple versions of CakePHP, including 1.3.13.

Comment: it's about your string charset, according to [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1187/clean) manual currently it does not support charset parameter, what charset do you use?

Comment: UTF-8. If I sanitize something from the database, all is well. I'm not too concerned about the fact that the "�" characters are appearing; it's just that the warning is being generated in the controller.

Comment: try ´echo '<p>Test: -' . utf8_encode($_GET['test']) . '-</p>';´ if not try ´echo '<p>Test: -' . utf8_decode($_GET['test']) . '-</p>';´ you a conflict of charset between the word, the encoding of the file per se or the encoding of cake or the encoding of php

Comment: @api55 wrapping `$_GET['test']` in `utf8_encode` works! Thanks! I'm still curious as to why the code causes a warning in the controller but not the view, though. It's the very same code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing the answer since to make it clearer for people who don't read comments :P

try

```
echo '<p>Test: -' . utf8_encode($_GET['test']) . '-</p>';
```

if not try

```
echo '<p>Test: -' . utf8_decode($_GET['test']) . '-</p>';
```

you have a conflict of charset between the word, the encoding of the file per se or the encoding of cake or the encoding of php

sanitize uses php function htmlentities, if it has the wrong encoding it may give you error on special characters (sanitize uses utf8 if not told other :S) you may use it with the utf8_encode to see it works also ;)

make sure your controller and view files are utf8 also your db and your cake config and your php server config, that way you shouldn't need the function :S hope it helps you (reboot server if necessary)

$_GET always get urldecoded (another php function), i assume it is decoded either to your php file encoding or the php.ini encoding configuration, not sure right now...

but anyway, if you keep your  encoding setups the same you won't have a problem and remember that the encoding of the php file is the file per se NOT the meta tag describing the charset...

Hope this helps you in the future :)